# MongoDB c# driver Find by ObjectId not working

Tags: c#, mongodb

I'm beating my head over this. Everything *should* be working as expected, according to the documentation. I'm using the latest driver (2.17.0) on .Net framework 4.7.2.

My PocoModel:

```
class Foo {
  [BsonId]
  public ObjectId Id {get;set;}
  ...
}
```

My query (this is a test I wrote to play with it):

```
var coll = db.GetCollection<Foo>("Foo");
            var objectId = ObjectId.Parse("62d78259134135e14915d602");
            var filter = Builders<Foo>.Filter.Eq(x => x.Id, objectId);
            var fnd = coll.Find(filter);
            var rec = fnd.FirstOrDefault();
            Assert.IsNotNull(rec);
```

If I look at the find object, I see `{find({ "_id" : ObjectId("62d78259134135e14915d602") }).limit(1)}`

If I copy and paste that to mongo shell, the find query returns the record as expected. When I run it in c#, no record is found.

Any ideas here?

Comment: Based on your class, the _id was a string but not ObjectId type.

Comment: Are you searching in the right collection? Is the collection name correct (typo?)?

Comment: I'm using the correct ObjectId type - I typed that rather than copying and pasting & slightly sleep deprived. 

I am indeed searching the correct collection - I can add to the collection just fine, it's just the retrieval by object ID that's not working.

Comment: I can't mark @JHBonarius' answer as correct, but it turns out I did indeed have a typo in my collection name in my code. I feel rather stupid for having overlooked a simple transposition, but that's what happened. So, for anyone else with a similar problem, make sure you look at your collection name!